# Insert large data set into room database

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I have run into a use-case for my app where I need to insert ~1000 records. My app is running into OOM now.

```
  @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    abstract fun insertAll(items: List<ItemEntity>)
```

I have tried:

```
bookEntityList.asSequence().chunked(50).forEach {
                bookDao.insertAll(it)
            }
```

But this does not work either. What is the best way to make such large inserts?

Here are the logs that I see:

```
2020-06-04 14:27:44.161  Background concurrent copying GC freed 4588(320KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 0% free, 95MB/96MB, paused 231us total 446.242ms
2020-06-04 14:27:44.161  WaitForGcToComplete blocked Alloc on HeapTrim for 445.238ms
2020-06-04 14:27:44.161  Starting a blocking GC Alloc
2020-06-04 14:27:44.162  WaitForGcToComplete blocked Alloc on HeapTrim for 443.251ms
2020-06-04 14:27:44.162  Starting a blocking GC Alloc
2020-06-04 14:27:44.162  WaitForGcToComplete blocked Alloc on HeapTrim for 14.494ms
2020-06-04 14:27:44.162  Starting a blocking GC Alloc
2020-06-04 14:27:44.190  Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
2020-06-04 14:27:44.190  Waiting for a blocking GC Alloc
```

Stacktrace:

```
       java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 1496 byte allocation with 328 free bytes and 328B until OOM, max allowed footprint 100663296, growth limit 100663296
        at android.icu.impl.ICUBinary.getShorts(ICUBinary.java:673)
        at android.icu.text.RBBIDataWrapper.get(RBBIDataWrapper.java:248)
        at android.icu.text.RuleBasedBreakIterator.getInstanceFromCompiledRules(RuleBasedBreakIterator.java:95)
        at android.icu.text.BreakIteratorFactory.createBreakInstance(BreakIteratorFactory.java:155)
        at android.icu.text.BreakIteratorFactory.createBreakIterator(BreakIteratorFactory.java:73)
        at android.icu.text.BreakIterator.getBreakInstance(BreakIterator.java:836)
        at android.icu.text.BreakIterator.getWordInstance(BreakIterator.java:565)
        at java.text.BreakIterator.getWordInstance(BreakIterator.java:457)
        at android.view.textclassifier.SelectionSessionLogger.getTokenIterator(SelectionSessionLogger.java:234)
        at android.widget.SelectionActionModeHelper$SelectionMetricsLogger.<init>(SelectionActionModeHelper.java:688)
        at android.widget.SelectionActionModeHelper$SelectionTracker.<init>(SelectionActionModeHelper.java:498)
        at android.widget.SelectionActionModeHelper.<init>(SelectionActionModeHelper.java:92)
        at android.widget.Editor.getSelectionActionModeHelper(Editor.java:2161)
        at android.widget.Editor.sendOnTextChanged(Editor.java:1358)
        at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:9800)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5760)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5598)
        at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:122)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:5555)
        at android.widget.TextView.setTransformationMethod(TextView.java:2441)
        at android.widget.TextView.applySingleLine(TextView.java:9493)
        at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:1460)
        at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:88)
        at android.widget.EditText.<init>(EditText.java:84)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:69)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init>(AppCompatEditText.java:65)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createEditText(AppCompatViewInflater.java:192)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:114)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1266)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1316)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:772)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
```

Comment: Can you post a stack trace of the `OutOfMemoryError`? I am interested to know what allocation is failing and how big it is. Also, is there anything particularly large in `ItemEntity` (e.g., BLOB column)?

Comment: @CommonsWare Added the logs and there are no blobs. There are a couple of enums and embedded objects. In total there are 15 columns.

Comment: That's not a stack trace, and it does not show an `OutOfMemoryError`. How have you reached the conclusion that is the basis of your question? What are your symptoms?

Comment: Updated with the correct stack trace. The app freezes and shows me an ANR dialog. It works fine when I remove the insert statement.

Comment: OK, you really are running out of memory, and for fairly small allocations too -- this isn't some "tried to allocate a 2MB buffer" sort of failure. However, the failure is in rendering a `TextView`, which is interesting -- I was expecting it to be somewhere in the Room logic. Doing this all in a single transaction, as with your first code snippet, could be a problem, but it doesn't sound like your rows are all that big.  In your second code snippet, with the sequence, are you running that in a `@Transaction` function? If not, then I'm baffled.

Comment: Yup, It's a transaction

Comment: OK, try temporarily removing the outer transaction, and see if the 20 calls to `insertAll()` now succeed. If that works, you are going to need to settle on some transaction size that you're comfortable with that is less than 1,000.

Comment: After debugging this a bit I found that the issue is with nested recycler views. The outer recycler view is taking a long time to measure the child recycler view size. Are there any solutions to make this efficient?

Comment: I recommend that you ask a separate question with its own [mcve] and a detailed explanation of the problem. I only use nested `RecyclerViews` when they are on opposite axes (e.g., a vertical `RecyclerView` whose items each are horizontal `RecyclerViews`).